# How to call firefox addon function with onclick in html

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am trying to write a program that scans for phone numbers with a regular expression. Then if it matches it should basically add an Image to the back of the phone number that should be click able and then call my function in my Firefox extension.

```
onDialerHandler: function(number){
  alert("onclick Event detected!");
},

onPageLoad : function(aEvent) {
if(aEvent.originalTarget.nodeName=="#document"){
  var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;

  var regex = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})/g;      

  var contents=doc.body.innerHTML;  

  var idx=contents.search("hello");
  if(idx) {
    var candidates = contents.match(regex);

    contents=contents.replace(regex,'($1) $2-$3<input id="testbutton" type="image" src="chrome://click2dial/content/images/call.png" name="image" onclick="onDialerHandler()"  width="15" height="15">');
    doc.body.innerHTML=contents;
    }  
  }
},
```

I am still very new to firefox addons and javascript. This is one way I have found to add the image but I am not able to process the onclick.

I have read up on people using "createElement" but I am just not able to get it working.

If there is any body that can help me with code to add my click able image the back of my regular expressing matches. One's the images is clicked the function onDialerHandler needs to be called.

I do believe I need help in not using the .replace function to get this working. Even pointing me in the right direction might help me allot?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a custom event in page and dispatch it.

```
  var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
  evt.initEvent("MY_EVENT", true, false);
  document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

on extension side you should create a listener to catch event.

```
document.addEventListener("MY_EVENT", myFunction, false, true);
```

If you want to pass some date, you can user event for this

```
  var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
  evt.someDate = "date";
 ....
```