# How to call JS function defined in Firefox extension from webpage?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I know it has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158326/how-to-call-firefox-addon-function-with-onclick-in-html) but it is not going to work for me. I am injecting following html from my extension's JS file. In same file I defined closepop() which should be executed onClick event but when I click it is not getting executed.

```
function openpop(obj){var refPopUpDiv = obj.getElementById('popUpDiv');refPopUpDiv.style.display = 'block';}
document.addEventListener("MY_EVENT", closepop, false, true);
function closepop()
{
    alert("Hurray from page")
}
var myExtension = {
    init: function() {
        // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.
        if(gBrowser) gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
    },
    onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
        var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event
        win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc
        var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        if(typeof doc !="undefined" && typeof head !="undefined")
        {
            addStyleSheet(head,doc,"picker.css");
        }
       // win.wrappedJSObject.testFunction();
        var style = doc.getElementById("link_picker");
        if(!style)
        {
            //alert("create");
        }
       //fire only when loaded
       if(doc.nodeName == "#document")
       {

           if(doc.location.href.indexOf("facebook.com") == -1) 
            {
                return;
            }
            if($(doc).find("#blueBar"))
            {
                var blue_bar =  $(doc).find("#blueBar");

                var themeURL1 = "theme1.css";
                var themeURL2 = "theme2.css";
                var themeURL3 = "theme3.css";
                var themeURL4 = "theme4.css";
                var themeURL5 = "theme5.css";
                var themeURL6  = "theme6.css";

                if(typeof blue_bar.html()!="undefined")
                {
                    var blueBarHtml = blue_bar.html();
                    var model1 = "http://oi43.tinypic.com/20ewx.jpg";
                    var model2 = "http://oi43.tinypic.com/20kc56x.jpg";
                    var model3 = "http://oi43.tinypic.com/3ec56x.jpg";
                    var model4 = "http://oi43.tinypic.com/ess.jpg";
                    var model5 = "http://oi43.tinypic.com/xx.jpg";
                    var model6 = "http://oi43.tinypic.com/210xx4526x.jpg";

                    var theme1text = "My Lovely ew";
                    var theme2text = "My Lovely Moewbile2";
                    var theme3text = "My Lovely Mobile3";
                    var theme4text = "My Lovely Mobile4";
                    var theme5text = "My Lovely Mobile5";
                    var theme6text = "My Lovely Mobile6";
                    //Propmo Text
                    var promoLeft = "All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.";
                    var promoRight = "All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.All My Mumbo JOb Goes here.";
                    var popUpDiv = "<div id ='popUpDiv' class='popUpDiv'><div class=close><a onclick='closepop();' title=Close href=#>X</a></div><div class=clearfix></div><div id=promoLeft>"+promoLeft+"</div><div id=modelContainer><a onclick='setTheme(\""+themeURL1+"\")' title='"+theme1text+"' href=#><img class=model src='"+model1+"' /></a><a onclick='setTheme(\""+themeURL2+"\")' title='"+theme2text+"' href=#><img class=model src='"+model2+"' /></a><a onclick='setTheme(\""+themeURL3+"\")' title='"+theme3text+"' href=#><img class=model src='"+model3+"' /></a><a onclick='setTheme(\""+themeURL4+"\")' title='"+theme4text+"' href=#><img class=model src='"+model4+"' /></a><a onclick='setTheme(\""+themeURL5+"\")' title='"+theme5text+"' href=#><img class=model src='"+model5+"' /></a><a onclick='setTheme(\""+themeURL6+"\")' title='"+theme6text+"' href=#><img class=model src='"+model6+"' /></a></div><div id=promoRight>"+promoRight+"</div><div id=save><input onclick='saveChanges();' type=button value='Save and Close' /></div></div>";
                    blue_bar.html(popUpDiv+blueBarHtml);
                }
            }
       }                                   
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    myExtension.init();  
},false);

//Add Style Sheet

function addStyleSheet(head,doc,file)
{
     var path = "chrome://xxx/content/"+file;
     var headHTML = "";
     if(head.innerHTML!="" && head.innerHTML!= null)
     {
        // alert();
         headHTML = head.innerHTML;
         var css1 = '<link id = "css_link0" id= type=text/css rel=stylesheet href='+path+'>';
         var js = '<script id=cust_evt>var evt = document.createEvent("Events");evt.initEvent("MY_EVENT", true, false);document.dispatchEvent(evt);</script>';
         head.innerHTML = headHTML+css1+js;
     }
}
```

Comment: Somehow I manage to trigger event. I needed to call CLICK event which worked but issue is that the function is being called even on page load! I don't know why but it is being. second my main purpose; to close DIV did not serve as yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("MY_EVENT", closepop, false, true);
```

Your `closepop` event is called on "MY_EVENT", not click, which is dispatched by addStyleSheet from the page load.